# how to send the http get request with dot in mojolicious

Tags: perl, jquery-mobile, get, gps, mojolicious

I develop an application in mojolicious framework with jquerymobile. It's about updating the GPS values to the SQLite3 database for every 3 seconds. I try to send the http Get request to store the gps value like `/v_id/latitude/longitude/updatetime/update` (route in .pm file in mojolicious). The value I send is: `/100/12.845323/77.4321455/3452687197281/update`  (value given in browser) but it does not store anything and shows an error of `There is no route matching the Get request`.

When i try like `/100/12845323/774321455/3452687197281/update` (without dots) it updated successfully. How do I send the request in http methods?

Comment: You have asked this exact same question on [www.webmasterwithus.com](http://www.webmasterwithus.com/news/how-to-send-the-http-get-request-with-dot-in-mojolicious/2013/05/04). Please don't cross-post.

Comment: please post a minimal example. I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the relaxed placeholders that accept dots. or wild card place holders that accept slashes also. see the mojolicious screencasts e2
http://mojocasts.com/e2